# MySQL Duplicate foreign key constraint name

Tags: mysql

I am trying to connect following tables, according to this model:

[image]

When I add a foreign key first time, say profile_id from PASSENGER_PROFILE is a FK to CREDIT_CARD_DETAILS, that runs fine.
However when I try to do the same to the TICKET_INFO table, I am getting an
**ERROR 1826: Duplicate foreign key constraint name**
The same thing when I add flight_id as a primary key, it works fine on FLIGHT_DETAILS but same error when I try to add it to the TICKET_INFO table.

All those keys are defined as primary keys in their respective tables (flight_id is PK in FLIGHT table and profile_id is PK in PASSENGER_PROFILE).
So I can't figure out why the MySQL Workbench displays an error as it should be possible to define the same PK as a FK in multiple tables.
Any suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have posted your create table-.

but in general

```
CONSTRAINT FK_PersonOrder FOREIGN KEY (PersonID)
REFERENCES Persons(PersonID)
```

but if i try to add

```
CONSTRAINT **FK_PersonOrder** FOREIGN KEY (OrderID)
REFERENCES Order(OrderID)
```

The name FK_PersonOrder is the same, and will cause the error you described

As you didn't post the complete error message, you have to look in youir create tables and eleminate all double names for foerign kegnb, the have to be unique

Comment: Thanks, that solves the issue. I haven't realized the FK names need to be unique (although they reference the same PK).